# Paginacao com ajax e php

Tags: php, ajax

Gente me ajudem por favaor ja olhei tudo e pesquisei a respeito mas nada funcionou
eu tenho uma tabela com id, nome, telefone e exibo essa tabela através da requisição Ajax pois eu uso um sistema de busca sem refresh

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'exibir.php',
        method: 'POST',
        data:'metodo=LISTAR_ARQUIVOS',
        beforeSend:function(){

        },
        success: function(resultado){
            $(".result").html(resultado);
        }

    });
});
```

e gostaria de adicionar um sistema de paginação com limite

```
$select = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM clientes LIMIT $inicio, $quantidade");
```

porem se eu uso um sistema de paginacao php normal não funciona

segue a baixo o exibir.php que o Ajax consulta, sem a paginacao php tradicional

```
<?php
    require('action/conexao.php');

    $metodo = $_POST['metodo'];

    switch($metodo){
        case 'LISTAR_ARQUIVOS':

            $pdo = Conexao::getInstance();

            $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM clientes");
            $stmt->execute();

            if($stmt->rowCount() >=1){
                while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)):
                    echo 
                    "<tr>
                        <td id='test'>". $row['nome'] ."</td>
                        <td>". $row['telefone'] ."</td>
                    ";
                    ?>
                <td>
                <ul class="actions">
                   <li><a href="" id="<?php echo $row['id'];?>" class="ative btnUpdate"><i class="fas fa-check"></i> Atualizar</a></li><!--
                --><li><a href="" class="cancel"><i class="far fa-eye"></i> Ver</a></li><!--
                --><li><a href="action/cnl.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'];?>" class="cancel"><i class="fas fa-times"></i> Cancel</a></li><!---->
                </ul>
            </td>


                    <?php

                endwhile;    
            echo "</tr>";
?> 


<?php        
            }else{
                echo ('Nenhuma pedido encontrado.');
            }
        break;

    }

?>
```

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta e explicar de maneira objetiva e pontual a dificuldade encontrada, acompanhada de um [mcve] do problema e tentativa de solução. Para aproveitar melhor o site, entender e evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena ler o [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/70).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Uma pessoa me respondeu por msg, e para aqueles que precisam ta ai a resposta.
ira precisar de 2 arquivos apenas um php e um js.

o tipo listagem exibi a lista do banco de dados

o tipo contador conta quando resultados tem no banco de dados

```
<?php
    require('action/conexao.php');

    $tipo = $_GET['tipo'];

        if($tipo=='listagem'){
        $pag    =   $_GET['pag'];
        $maximo =   $_GET['maximo'];
        $inicio =   ($pag * $maximo) - $maximo; //Variável para LIMIT da sql
     

            $pdo = Conexao::getInstance();

            $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM pedidos WHERE nivel=:ni LIMIT $inicio, $maximo");
            $stmt->bindValue(':ni', '1');
            $stmt->execute();

            if($stmt->rowCount() >=1){
                while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)):
                    echo 
                    "<tr>
                        <td>". $row['revista'] ."</td>
                        <td>". $row['quantidade'] ."</td>
                        <td>". $row['pedido'] ."<br><small>Criado:  ". $row['data'] ."</small></td>
                        <td>". $row['codigo'] ."</td>
                        <td>". $row['preco'] ."</td>
                    ";
                    ?>
                <td>
               
            </td>


                    <?php
                 echo "</tr>";
                endwhile; 
            }else{}       
           

    }elseif($tipo=='contador'){
        $pdo = Conexao::getInstance();

        $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM pedidos WHERE nivel=:ni");
        $stmt->bindValue(':ni', '1');
        $stmt->execute();

        $contar = $stmt->rowCount();
        
        if($contar > 0){
            echo $contar;
        }

    }else{
        echo 'solicitação invalida';
    }


?>
```

```
<script>
var quantidade = 1; //quantidade de itens a ser mostrado por página
var pg = 1; //página inicial - DEIXE SEMPRE 1

$(document).ready(function(){
    getitens(pg,quantidade); //Chamando função que lista os itens
})
    function getitens(pag, maximo){ 
    pg = pag; 
    $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    data: 'tipo=listagem&pag='+pag +'&maximo='+maximo,
    url:'exibir.php',
    success: function(retorno){
        $('.result').html(retorno); 
            contador() //Chamando função que conta os itens e chama o paginador
        }
    })
}

function contador(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        data: 'tipo=contador',
        url:'exibir.php',
        success: function(retorno_pg){
            paginador(retorno_pg) 
        }
    })
}
function paginador(cont){

    var totalRegistros = cont;

    if(totalRegistros<=quantidade){
        
    }else{
        $('.paginas').html('<tr></tr>');
        var qtdpaginas  =  Math.ceil(totalRegistros/quantidade)

    var links = 2;
    //desabiltiar ele depois
    if(pg<=1){$('.paginas').append('<a href="#" class="primeira"><i class="fas fa-arrow-left"></i></a>')}
    else{

    $('.paginas').append('<a href="#" class="primeira" id="middle"  onclick="getitens('+(pg-1)+', '+quantidade+')"><i class="fas fa-arrow-left"></i></a>')
}
    for(var i=pg-links; i <= pg-1;i++){
        if(i<=0){}
        else{
            $('.paginas').append('<a href="#" id="middle" onclick="getitens('+i+', '+quantidade+')">'+i+'</a>')
        }
    }
    //pagina ativa
    $('.paginas').append('<a href="#" id="middle" class="ativo" onclick="getitens('+i+', '+quantidade+')">'+pg+'</a>')

    for(var i=pg+1; i <= pg+links;i++){
        if(i>pg+1){}
        else{
            if(pg != qtdpaginas){
            $('.paginas').append('<a href="#" id="middle" onclick="getitens('+i+', '+quantidade+')">'+i+'</td>')
            }else{}
        }
    }

    if(pg != qtdpaginas){
        $('.paginas').append('<a href="#" class="ultima" onclick="getitens('+(pg+1)+', '+quantidade+')"><i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i></a>')
    }else{
        // Desabilitar o botao ultima pagina
        $('.paginas').append('<a href="#" class="ultima"><i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i></a>')
    }   
    }
   
}
</script>
```

Comment: Se está solução resolveu seu problema marque como resposta aceita para que a pergunta seja fechada.